# how to put odd page number on the left side of the birt report

Tags: birt

In my BIRT report, I need to start the page number from second page of the report, and need to put page number left or right side of the report according to odd or even page. Is there any way I can achieve above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Report may have different Master Pages on different pages. Create one Master Page with page numbering visible, one without. In the element starting new page select required Master Page in Property Editor -> Page Break -> Master Page.

For the second part it is not the real answer, but only my comment about. Changing way of page numbering was subject of many BIRT bugs and it may work only in some BIRT versions. It is the matter of affecting Master Page content by report content, while Master Pages are generated before report. See examples in Eclipse forum:

[How to restart page numbering within a group in BIRT 3.7.1](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/840198/)
[Page number and total page](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/273065/)

Comment: [link](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/?/blog/10/entry-20-birt-multiple-master-pages-with-no-scripting/) . I ahve used this guide to use different masetr page, I have different margins for First and Second Master page, but for all page the margin of second page get applied. How can I get margin of the first master page is applied to the first page.

Comment: Hi Sundar , when I ahve done your way for page number , my second page starting with 2, I need it to start with 1, any idea how to do this?